# Why the thread may be blocked for longer than the specified duration when we use wait_for?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In 《c++ concurrency in action》page 387.

```
 template<typename Lockable, typename Rep, typename Period>
  std::cv_status wait_for(
       Lockable& lock,
       std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> const& relative_time);
```

NOTE The spurious wakeups mean that a thread calling `wait_for()` may wake even though no thread has called `notify_one()` or `notify_all()`. It’s therefore recommended that the overload of `wait_for()` that takes a predicate is used in preference where possible. Otherwise, it’s recommended that `wait_for()` be called in a loop that tests the predicate associated with the condition variable. Care must be taken when doing this to ensure that the timeout is still valid; `wait_until()` may be more appropriate in many circumstances. **The thread may be blocked for longer than the specified duration.** Where possible, the elapsed time is determined by a steady clock.

Why the thread may be blocked for longer than the specified duration when we use `wait_for()`?

Comment: OS may not schedule the thread until a later time.  Thread has to be awake to check the lock; but non busy waiting will cause a yield, so the lock will only be checked next time the OS wakes up the thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [cppreference:`std::condition_variable::wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for)

> This function may block for longer than timeout_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

When the duration expires, the thread is asleep and needs to be re-scheduled. The kernel scheduler often runs on a timer or when some other event prompts it, and when it starts it will take some time, and even then there may be no free core to schedule your thread on.

When your thread *is* scheduled, the first thing that happens is `wait_for` re-acquiring the lock before returning control to your code. This is itself a blocking operation if another thread is currently holding that lock.

Comment: When re-scheduled, the first thing is re-acquiring the lock, not checking whether it is timeout or not?

Comment: Depends how the sleep/wakeup is handled. If it knows it woke due to the timer expiring and not due to an interrupt, there wouldn't need to be an extra check.

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems do not generally prevent you from writing or running programs that attempt to use more resources than the system has available. The OS won't stop you from running your system out of disk space. It won't stop your programs from running out of memory. It won't stop your programs from malfunctioning because they need more network bandwidth than your ISP provides. And, No OS (that I know of) will stop you from running threads and/or program that already will be using all of the available CPU cores at the exact moment when you wished that one thread would wake up.

If you need better ability to precisely control when certain threads in your program will wake up and do things, then you might be needing a *[real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)*.